Conditional include by if condition for EF Core 8
I don't know to what extent what I have in mind will be done. But I'll try my luck to find someone here who can explain it to me.
I have following method in my DB repository:
public async Task<IList<BroadcastEntryEntity>> GetByPeriodOfTimeOfProgramAsync(Guid programId, DateTime dateTimeStartUtc,
                                                                               DateTime dateTimeEndUtc, bool includePrograms = false,
                                                                               bool includePlayouts = false, bool includeRecords = false)
{
    return await Set.Include(broadcastEntry => broadcastEntry.Program)
                    .Include(broadcastEntry => broadcastEntry.PlayoutInstance)
                    .Include(broadcastEntry => broadcastEntry.Record)
                    .ThenInclude(record => record.ContentTags)
                    .Include(broadcastEntry => broadcastEntry.Record)
                    .ThenInclude(record => record.ExternalIds)
                    .Where(item => item.ProgramId == programId &&
                                   item.BroadcastDateTimeUtcStart >= dateTimeStartUtc &&
                                   item.BroadcastDateTimeUtcEnd <= dateTimeEndUtc)
                    .OrderBy(broadcastEntry => broadcastEntry.BroadcastDateTimeUtcStart)
                    .ToListAsync();
}

This works great so far. I'm just wondering how I could optionally exclude the includes using the method parameters: includePrograms, includePlayouts, includeRecords?
Is it possible to do something like what the example here suggests (I know it can't work like that):
public async Task<IList<BroadcastEntryEntity>> GetByPeriodOfTimeOfProgramAsync(Guid programId, DateTime dateTimeStartUtc,
                                                                               DateTime dateTimeEndUtc, bool includePrograms = false,
                                                                               bool includePlayouts = false, bool includeRecords = false)
{
    if (includePrograms){
        // Include the programs
        var programInclude = Set.Include(broadcastEntry => broadcastEntry.Program)
    }

    if (includePlayouts){
        // Include the playout instances
        var playoutInclude = Set.Include(broadcastEntry => broadcastEntry.PlayoutInstances)
    }

    if (includeRecords){
        // Include the records
        var recordInclude = Set.Include(broadcastEntry => broadcastEntry.Record)
                    .ThenInclude(record => record.ContentTags)
                    .Include(broadcastEntry => broadcastEntry.Record)
                    .ThenInclude(record => record.ExternalIds)
    }

    return await Set.Where(item => item.ProgramId == programId &&
                                   item.BroadcastDateTimeUtcStart >= dateTimeStartUtc &&
                                   item.BroadcastDateTimeUtcEnd <= dateTimeEndUtc)
                    .OrderBy(broadcastEntry => broadcastEntry.BroadcastDateTimeUtcStart)
                    .ToListAsync();
}

Or am I on the wrong track here and do something like this completely differently?
I would be very grateful for any advice here.

Protip: make your Linq more readable by using shorter names, like be instead of broadcastEntry.

"Is it possible to do something like what the example here suggests " - actually, you're not far-off...

You can convert the query to iqueryable and do all those checks. Then at the end if needed convert the iqueryable to list or something depending on your requirements.

Does this answer your question? How can I conditionally apply a Linq operator?

Many of the "smart" answers in that question will result in inefficient execution plans because they pass the condition value to the database as a parameter, resulting in inefficient execution plans

LINQ operators are functions that return a new query. That means one can easily construct the query piece by piece with eg if (x) { query = query.Include(...;);} and then apply the conditions with eg query=query.Where(....).OrderBy(). Once the full query is complete, var results = await query.ToListAsync(); will execute it


Is it possible to do something like what the example here suggests

...actually, you're not far-off:
public async Task< IReadOnlyList<BroadcastEntryEntity> > GetByPeriodOfTimeOfProgramAsync(
    Guid     programId,
    DateTime dateTimeStartUtc,
    DateTime dateTimeEndUtc,
    bool     includePrograms = false,
    bool     includePlayouts = false,
    bool     includeRecords  = false,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default
)
{
    IQueryable<BroadcastEntryEntity> query = this.BroadcastEntryEntities; // <-- I assume this is your DbContext.DbSet<T>'s name.

    if (includePrograms)
    {
        // Include the programs
        query = query.Include(be => be.Program);
    }

    if (includePlayouts)
    {
        query = query.Include(be => be.PlayoutInstances);
    }

    if (includeRecords)
    {
        query = query
            .Include(be => be.Record).ThenInclude(r => r.ContentTags)
            .Include(be => be.Record).ThenInclude(r => r.ExternalIds);
    }

    List<BroadcastEntryEntity> list = await query
        .Where(be => be.ProgramId == programId)
        .Where(be => be.BroadcastDateTimeUtcStart == dateTimeStartUtc)
        .Where(be => be.BroadcastDateTimeUtcEnd == dateTimeEndUtc)
        .Where(be => be.ProgramId == programId)
        .OrderBy(be => be.BroadcastDateTimeUtcStart)
        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return list;
}



I advocate using IReadOnlyList<> as a collection return-type instead of IList<> because it allows you to return an immutable collection, and to avoid allocations entirely when returning an empty-result with Array.Empty<T>(), for example.
Don't forget to pass CancellationToken!
The chained .Where() in my answer will be translated to SQL that's identical to your single .Where() - I just think this approach is easier to read.


I think it's better to separate the part that applies Where  and OrderBy  to the query from the actual execution. I suspect the next question will be how to apply Where dynamically

Wow, and learned something new again.
I wasn't even aware of the conversion to IQueryable. But if you look at it closer it becomes clear.

@Marcus Conversion?

@Dai Okay, implicit cast to IQueryable<BroadcastEntryEntity> i mean
